# Specify runner to be used depending on condition in a GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

We have two runners, one for running production jobs and another for running non production jobs, but I am unable to do that using a workflow level environment variable.

Below is what I have:

```
name: Workflow file

on:
  workflow-dispatch

env:
 RUNNER_NAME: ${{ contains(github.ref, 'main') && 'Prod Runner' || 'non-Prod Runner' }}

jobs:
  job-run:
    runs-on: [${{ env.RUNNER_NAME }}]
    needs: ...
    steps:
      ..........
```

I get the following error message:

**Invalid workflow file**

```
You have an error in your yaml syntax on line ###
```

How do I do this? I don't want to have separate workflow files for prod and non-prod workflows.

Comment: How does this expression work exactly: `${{ contains(github.ref, 'main') && 'Prod Runner' || 'non-Prod Runner' }}`? What are the expected outputs?

Comment: I figured this out afterwards using ```runs-on: ${{ contains(github.ref, 'main') && 'Prod Runner' || 'Cert Runner' }}``` as it picks the Production Runner if I'm on the main branch and the Cert Runner in all other cases.

Comment: Ok, I've made some tests and shared my answer below 

Answer (score 6):

For what you can check on this [Github Actions ISSUE](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/480), it seems **it's not possible to use natively `env` variable on the `runs-on` job field** (yet?).

---

However, there is a workaround if you configure a variable as output in a previous job, so you would be able to use it afterwards.

**Example:** `runs-on: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.runner }}`

In your case, the workflow would look like this:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      runner: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.runner }}
    steps:
      - name: Check branch
        id: step1
        run: |
          if [ ${{ github.ref }} == 'refs/heads/main' ]; then
            echo "runner=ubuntu-latest" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          else
            echo "runner=macos-latest" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          fi

  job1:
    needs: [setup]
    runs-on: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.runner }}
    steps:
      - run: echo "My runner is ${{ needs.setup.outputs.runner }}" #ubuntu-latest if main branch
```

I've made a test here if you want to have a look:

- [workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester31.yml)
- [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/6133382192?check_suite_focus=true)

Comment: This trick does not work if you want to use multiple labels.

Comment: This workaround won't work after 31.05.2023
https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/

Comment: I've updated the answer to use the new syntax to set outputs. Thanks for noticing @maximkrouk

Comment: As I think @evilfish is already trying to say this (unfortunately) does not seem to work with a strategy-matrix for the runners (as somewhat stated elsewhere by @GuiFalourd). Or if I'm wrong, I would love to see a version of that. I've tried something like 'strategy: matrix: fromJson(needs.setup.outputs.runners)'.

Comment: How did you generate the output in that case @AudioDroid? (If you want to open another question with that scenario, we can perform some tests and evaluate how to make it work!)