# Github action runner does not react to self-hosted labels from Environments

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I am currently trying to create some dynamic workflow files so I can deploy to different self-hosted runners using the environment variable system. I follow the work around in this post: [Specify runner to be used depending on condition in a GitHub Actions workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71961921/specify-runner-to-be-used-depending-on-condition-in-a-github-actions-workflow)

The idea is to use a step to generate output where you get the variable from the selected environment to be used in a steps 'runs-on:' setting. Currently this is my workflow file, with removed stuff for simplicity:

```yaml
name: Dashboard - Publish and deploy
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        type: environment
        description: Select the environment
      buildConfiguration:
      <removed for simplicity>

jobs:
  setup:
    name: Setup runner labels for deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
    outputs:
      deployrunner: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.deployrunner }}
    steps:
      - name: Set runs-on for deploy
        id: step1
        run: |
          echo "deployrunner=${{ vars.DEPLOYSERVER }}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  build:
    <removed for simplicity>
        
  deployDashboard:
    needs: [build, setup]
    runs-on: ${{needs.setup.outputs.deployrunner}}
    name: Deploy dashboard to server
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
    env:
      ServiceBaseDir: ${{ vars.DASHBOARD_DIR }}  

    steps:     
    <removed for simplicity>
```

The problem is that this does not seem to work. If I exchange the `runs-on: ${{needs.setup.outputs.deployrunner}` to `runs-on: [self-hosted,dev1]` the runner on dev1 will see it and start up:

```
> Requested labels: self-hosted, dev1
> Job defined at: <redacted>/.github/workflows/<redacted>
> Waiting for a runner to pick up this job...
> Job is about to start running on the runner: dev1 (repository) <-- job started
```

But when I use the output variable, I can see that the labels are correctly applied but the runner never sees it:

```
> Requested labels: self-hosted, dev1
> Job defined at: <redacted>/.github/workflows/<redacted>
> Waiting for a runner to pick up this job...
```

And it continues to wait. If I then switch back to the explicit runs-on notation, it works again.

I have tried to restart the dev1 server and/or restart the runner, but to no effect. In the environment variable, the `vars.DEPLOYSERVER` variable is set to `self-hosted, dev1` but I have also tried `[self-hosted, dev1]` with no change. The runners version is 2.301.1, which is only one version behind. Checked the release notes (https://github.com/actions/runner/releases) and the changes does not indicate any changes related to this.

Anyone know if this is a know bug for self-hosted runners that I could not find or knows what is going on here?

## Update 2023-03-06

I was building a bug report when I found out that this trick does work on local runners. It does not work, however, if you use multiple labels. If you use `self-hosted, dev1` the local runner will not work. But if you only supply `dev1` it does work. Its not possible at the moment to add the variable inside brackets of the runs-on, as the workflow parser sees this as an error.